# Accessing CentOS User Logs

Tags: centos, log-files

CentOS log that records everything that is done on the server by a certain user?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Record everything on command line centos /fedora/ ubuntu](http://serverfault.com/questions/140347/record-everything-on-command-line-centos-fedora-ubuntu)

Comment: Also: http://serverfault.com/questions/128222/monitor-the-shell-activity-of-a-user-on-your-unix-system/128248#128248

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question: No. CentOS doesn't really record everything a user does. You could view their .bash_history file as kenny.r suggests, but they can delete this file if they want.

What you are looking for is process accounting, you can get a quick and simply introduction to it here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-log-user-activity-using-process-accounting.html

Answer (score 2):

cat .bash_history

or  simply

history

Answer (score 1):

You can check the **.bash_history** file in that user's home directory to see the commands he has performed.